# Why UnicodeDecodeError when saving matplotlib animation?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I try to use the following code to generate animation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import ArtistAnimation

fig = plt.figure() 
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111) 

ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim(-2,2)

dt = 0.01
q  = 0.01
t = np.arange(0,1,dt)
x = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
images = []

for i in xrange(100):
    x = (1-q) * x + q* np.random.normal(size = len(t))
    line, = ax.plot(t,x, '-')
    images.append((line,))

line_anim = ArtistAnimation(fig, images, interval=50, blit=True)

#line_anim.save('my_animation.mp4')
#line_anim.save('my_animation.gif')

plt.show()
```

It works fine. I see the animation that I expect to see. However, if I try to save it into a ``mp4`or`gif` file (by uncommenting the corresponding line of the code) I get the following error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position 5: ordinal
not in range(128)
```

Does anybody know what is happening there and how the problem can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that if you do not specify a dedicated writer in `Animation.save`, it uses the rcParam value for `animation.writer`. I assume that your matplotlib installation does not specify a correct value for that parameter hence the error.

You should specify a writer in `save` method (and anyway control your matplotlib installation):

```
line_anim.save('my_animation.mp4', writer = 'ffmpeg')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not help. I still get the same error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position 5`

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem when trying to run

```
ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(...)
ani.save("out.gif", writer="imagemagick", dpi=80,fps=10)
```

on a windows machine using matplotlib 1.5.

The problem is that matplotlib wants to call the `convert` binary of imagemagick. However in windows there is another standard tool `convert` available which is called instead and the output of which causes this unicode error. To prevent this from happening the full path to imagemagick's convert needs to be made available to matplotlib through the `"animation.convert_path"`rcparam.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["animation.convert_path"] = r"D:\Programs\ImageMagick\convert.exe" 
                                            #or whatever the full path is.
```